# Rebinding RET without rebinding <kp-enter>

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, keyboard-layout

My Emacs translates `C-m` as RET like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7235381/unbind-c-m-from-ret. I'd like to use `C-m` though, and I have a multilevel keyboard-layout in which `<kp-enter>` is much more convenient to reach than RET anyway. So I'd like to continue using `<kp-enter>` as it is now while rebinding `C-m`/RET. Is there a way to do this without having to manually rebind `<kp-enter>` to any function RET fulfills in any mode? For instance, could I rebind `C-m` to some other key combination while leaving `<kp-enter>` to point to where `C-m` was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going around re-binding all the bindings of `RET` would be tedious, so you can just leave them alone, and translate `C-m` to a different key, and then bind that. Of course that still leaves `RET` and `<kp-enter>` the same:

```
(key-translate "C-m" "C-z")
(keymap-local-set "C-z" (key-parse "hello world"))
```

In versions of Emacs prior to emacs-29 `key-translate` and `keymap-local-set` are not available, so do the following instead:

```
(keyboard-translate ?\C-m ?\C-z)
(local-set-key (kbd "C-z") "helloworld")
```

Comment: When I try out your first command I get `Wrong type argument: fixnump, [13]`.

Comment: @AlexanderPraehauser: See [commit 93134bb9](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?h=emacs-29&id=93134bb9c2f46b906b1b31b8fec264123d1962ee).

Answer (score 2):

By default, **`<kp-enter>` runs `[13]` (see `function-key-map`) which equals a single `C-m`.**

So,

> Is there a way to do this without having to manually rebind `<kp-enter>` to any function RET fulfills in any mode?

I'm afraid there's no way to do that.

---

> could I rebind `C-m` to some other key combination while leaving `<kp-enter>` to point to where `C-m` was?

Yes.
This may help: 
(Thanks for @PRouleau's comment.
Based on it, I rewrote the code to be more thoughtful.)

```lisp
;; Take `ielm-mode' for example.
(add-hook 'ielm-mode-hook
          (letrec ((RET-rebinder
                    (lambda ()
                      ;; Before you rebind "<kp-enter>",
                      ;; evaluate the following expression:
                      (keymap-local-set "<kp-enter>"
                                        (if-let ((local-ret (keymap-local-lookup "C-m")))
                                            ;; `ielm-mode' binds "C-m" to a useful command,
                                            ;; you probably want it:
                                            local-ret  
                                          (keymap-global-lookup "C-m")))
                      ;; Then do rebinding:
                      (keymap-local-set "C-m" 'previous-line)
                      ;; The above expressions need to be executed only once.
                      (remove-hook 'ielm-mode-hook RET-rebinder))))
            RET-rebinder))
```

Comment: Note that ``(key-binding [13])`` is major-mode specific so the binding you'd globally assign to "<kp-enter>" would be the mode-specific binding of [13] of the active major mode when the command is evaluated.

Comment: This is the kind of thing that's best done in a `with-eval-after-load` expression, then you don't need to do the `remove-hook`